# Can't write data in an excel file in a customized way

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a macro to fetch some content from a webpage and write the same in an excel file in a customized manner. I've used two identical links from the same website. Here is [one](https://www.chelseasmessyapron.com/caprese-quinoa-salad/) of them. I'm interested in three fields `Name`,`Recipe` and `Ingredients`.

The script that I've created can parse the data accordingly. However, I wanna arrange them in an excel file like ***[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZGvK.jpg)***.

I've written so far (working flawlessly):

```
Sub GetAndArrangeData()
    Dim HTML As New HTMLDocument, oPost As Object
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument, ws As Worksheet
    Dim oTitle As Object, oPosts As Object
    Dim linklist As Variant, url As Variant
    
    linklist = Array( _
        "https://www.chelseasmessyapron.com/avocado-chicken-salad-2/", _
        "https://www.chelseasmessyapron.com/caprese-quinoa-salad/" _
    )
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    For Each url In linklist
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36"
            .send
            HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
        
        Set oTitle = HTML.querySelector("h1.entry-title")
        Debug.Print oTitle.innerText

        Set oPost = HTML.querySelectorAll(".cma-recipe-nutrition > .wprm-nutrition-label-container > span[class*='nutrition-container']")
        For I = 0 To oPost.Length - 1
            HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oPost(I).outerHTML
            Debug.Print HTMLDoc.querySelector("span.wprm-nutrition-label-text-nutrition-label").innerText
            Debug.Print HTMLDoc.querySelector("span[class*='nutrition-value']").innerText
        Next I

        Set oPosts = HTML.querySelectorAll(".wprm-recipe-block-container")
        For I = 0 To oPosts.Length - 1
            HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oPosts(I).outerHTML
            On Error Resume Next
            Debug.Print HTMLDoc.querySelector("span.wprm-recipe-details-label").innerText
            Debug.Print HTMLDoc.querySelector("span.wprm-recipe-details").innerText
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next I
    Next url
End Sub
```

> How can I write the data in an excel file the way I've shown in the image above?

Btw, this is the result I got in the immediate window:

```
Avocado Chicken Salad
Calories: 
542
Carbohydrates: 
30
Protein: 
11
Fat: 
45
Saturated Fat: 
7
Cholesterol: 
16
Sodium: 
285
Potassium: 
687
Fiber: 
8
Sugar: 
9
Vitamin A: 
945
Vitamin C: 
19
Calcium: 
36
Iron: 
1
Course 
Cuisine 
Keyword 
Prep Time 
20
Cook Time 
15
Total Time 
35
Servings 
2
Calories 
542
Cost 
$6.82
Caprese Quinoa Salad
Calories: 
375
Carbohydrates: 
30
Protein: 
11
Fat: 
26
Saturated Fat: 
4
Cholesterol: 
7
Sodium: 
73
Potassium: 
996
Fiber: 
9
Sugar: 
7
Vitamin A: 
17616
Vitamin C: 
32
Calcium: 
168
Iron: 
4
Course 
Cuisine 
Keyword 
Prep Time 
35
Cook Time 
25
Chilling Time (Quinoa) 
1
Total Time 
2
Servings 
6
Calories 
375
Cost 
$6.84
```

Comment: What do you mean by "working flawlessly"? I tried testing it and both lines trying to define `oPosts` object, return 'Null`. I mean `Set oPosts = ...`. Is it necessary to be registered?

Comment: Check out the output that I get in the immediate window when I execute the macro @FaneDuru. Nope, nothing  is required to fetch the results. Just run it the way it is. Thanks.

Comment: I copied it as it is and only try running. It returns  a correct .`responseText`, correct `oTitle.innerText`, but it allways returns `Set oPost = HTML.querySelectorAll("....` as `Null`... No `oPost.Length` and no any iteration. If I would obtain the 'result' you show (in Immediate Window) I could show you how to arrange it in sheet as you need.

Comment: Did you actually want the keyword, course and cuisine?

Comment: Nope. I actually want to kick them out @QHarr.

Comment: I'll have a look at it tomorrow/wednesday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you just need to keep track where to write the data. I define a variable `row` that is set to the first row where you want to put data into. After every recipe, the number of rows written is added to `row`. To keep track of the number of rows, I am using two separate variables `oPostNut` and oPostsRecipe`(instead of only one`oPosts`) and add the number of entries of the larger list - that's basically all.

```
(...)
Dim row As Long
row = 1         ' Change to whatever row you want to start
For Each url In linklist
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set oTitle = HTML.querySelector("h1.entry-title")
    ws.Cells(row, 1) = oTitle.innerText

    Dim i As long
    Dim oPostsNut As Object
    Set oPostsNut = HTML.querySelectorAll(".cma-recipe-nutrition > .wprm-nutrition-label-container > span[class*='nutrition-container']")        
    For i = 0 To oPostsNut.Length - 1
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oPostsNut(i).outerHTML
        ws.Cells(row + i, 2) = HTMLDoc.querySelector("span.wprm-nutrition-label-text-nutrition-label").innerText
        ws.Cells(row + i, 3) = HTMLDoc.querySelector("span[class*='nutrition-value']").innerText
    Next i

    Dim oPostsRecipe As Object
    Set oPostsRecipe = HTML.querySelectorAll(".wprm-recipe-block-container")
    For i = 0 To oPostsRecipe.Length - 1
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oPostsRecipe(i).outerHTML
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.Cells(row + i, 4) = HTMLDoc.querySelector("span.wprm-recipe-details-label").innerText
        ws.Cells(row + i, 5) = HTMLDoc.querySelector("span.wprm-recipe-details").innerText
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
    
    row = row + IIf(oPostsNut.Length > oPostsRecipe.Length, oPostsNut.Length, oPostsRecipe.Length)
Next url
```

Answer (score 2):

I think we can do better. If we use a more selective css selector we can get rid of the additional info that I am seeing in other answer (12/02/21) and your original attempt. Using the selector below I remove that additional info and only return desired info. I work with an array as is faster than writing to sheet all the time. I remove the need for re-creating xmlhttp object and the additional HTMLDocument.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetAndArrangeData()
    Dim html As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Dim linklist As Variant, url As Variant, totalRows
    
    linklist = Array( _
        "https://www.chelseasmessyapron.com/avocado-chicken-salad-2/", _
        "https://www.chelseasmessyapron.com/caprese-quinoa-salad/" _
    )
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    totalRows = 1
    
    For Each url In linklist
       
       With xhr
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36"
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
        
        Dim title As String
        
        title = html.querySelector("h1.entry-title").innerText
    
        Dim nutritionRows As Object, timesOtherRows As Object, maxRows As Long
        
        Set nutritionRows = html.querySelectorAll(".wprm-nutrition-label-container .wprm-nutrition-label-text-nutrition-container")
        Set timesOtherRows = html.querySelectorAll(".cma-recipe-mobile .wprm-recipe-times-container .wprm-recipe-block-container-columns, .wprm-recipe-meta-container ~ .wprm-recipe-block-container-columns")

        maxRows = IIf(nutritionRows.Length > timesOtherRows.Length, nutritionRows.Length, timesOtherRows.Length) - 1

        Dim recipeInfo(), i As Long
        ReDim recipeInfo(1 To maxRows, 1 To 5)
        
        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 0 To maxRows
            recipeInfo(i + 1, 1) = IIf(i = 0, title, vbNullString)
            recipeInfo(i + 1, 2) = nutritionRows.Item(i).Children(0).innerText
            recipeInfo(i + 1, 3) = nutritionRows.Item(i).Children(1).innerText
            recipeInfo(i + 1, 4) = timesOtherRows.Item(i).Children(1).innerText
            recipeInfo(i + 1, 5) = timesOtherRows.Item(i).Children(2).innerText
        Next
        On Error GoTo 0
       
        ws.Cells(totalRows, 1).Resize(UBound(recipeInfo, 1), UBound(recipeInfo, 2)) = recipeInfo
        totalRows = totalRows + maxRows
    Next url
End Sub
```

---

**JSON:**

Perhaps easier though is to grab all the info as json from a `script` tag in the HEAD part of the response. You will need to wrap the response in `body` tags to prevent the HTML parser stripping this content out when you add it into the `MSHTML.HTMLDocument` object's `body.innerHTML`.

I am not going to show the json parsing as there are plenty of example but will show extracting it.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetAndArrangeData()
    Dim html As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object
    Dim linklist As Variant, url As Variant
    
    linklist = Array( _
        "https://www.chelseasmessyapron.com/avocado-chicken-salad-2/", _
        "https://www.chelseasmessyapron.com/caprese-quinoa-salad/" _
    )
    
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    For Each url In linklist
       
       With xhr
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36"
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = "<body>" & .responseText & "</body>"
        End With
        
        Debug.Print html.querySelector(".yoast-schema-graph").innerHTML
        
    Next url
End Sub
```